# Parsing string into DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a string and I have to convert it into DateTime type.

```
'11 Jun 2015 (12:10)'
```

I have to parse it into DateTime. I have used `DateTime.Parse("MyDateString")` but it is throwing an exception.

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have to split the string than convert it to DateTime format or there is an easy way?

Comment: From the link ckryczek cited above: "DateTime.Parse() will try figure out the format of the given date, and it usually does a good job. If you can guarantee dates will always be in a given format then you can use ParseExact()"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` uses [standard date and time format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx) of your `CurrentCulture`. Since your string has `(` and `)`, you need to use [custom date and time parsing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`TryParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method (or [`ParseExact`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.ParseExact.aspx)) with an *english-based* culture (eg: [`InvariantCulture`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) like;

```
string s = "11 Jun 2015 (12:10)";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd MMM yyyy '('HH:mm')'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 11.06.2015 12:10:00
}
```

If your string has `'` in the begining and at the end, you can escape them with `"\\'dd MMM yyyy '('HH:mm')'\\'"` format like;

```
string s = "'11 Jun 2015 (12:10)'";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "\\'dd MMM yyyy '('HH:mm')'\\'", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    // 11.06.2015 12:10:00
}
```